# I can't insert row into database - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem with inserting row into sqlite using ModelForm. I realy don;t see what am I doing wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks!
This is my view:

```
def row(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST  or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_publisher=form.save
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            website = form.cleaned_data['website']
            p=Publisher(
                name=name,
                city=city,
                address=address,
                website =website,
                state_province='example_content1',
                country='example_content2'
                )
            p.save
            results=Publisher.objects.all()
        else:
            form.errors
    return render_to_response('after_subbmission.html', locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my model:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    website=models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my form:

```
class Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Publisher
```

And this is my html:

```
<form action="/row/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

<table style="border:solid 1px black; width:300px";>
<tr>
<th style="border:solid 1px black";>name</th><th style="border:solid 1px  black";>adress</th>
<th style="border:solid 1px black";>city</th>
<th style="border:solid 1px black";>website</th>
<th style="border:solid 1px black";>id</th>
<th style="border:solid 1px black";>State Province</th>
<th style="border:solid 1px black";>Country</th>
 <tr>
 <td style="border:solid 1px black";><input type="text" name="name" value= {{choose.name}}></td><td style="border:solid 1px black";><input type="text" name="address"  value={{choose.address}} ></td>
 <td style="border:solid 1px black";><input type="text" name="city" value={{choose.city}} ></td>
 <td style="border:solid 1px black";><input type="text" name="website" value={{choose.website}} ></td>
  <td style="border:solid 1px black";><input type="text" name="id" value={{choose.id}} ></td>
  <td style="border:solid 1px black";><input type="text" name="state_province" value={{choose.state_province}} ></td>
   <td style="border:solid 1px black";><input type="text" name="country" value={{choose.country}} ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Of course I've imported all necessary classes and forms and no errors after submission occure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the data. You have to call `p.save()`. Add `()` on your `p.save` code. It will work.

Comment: Thanks !! Stupid mistake.

Comment: What was the point of duplicating the same answer after 3 hours it was posted?

Answer (score 4):

You are not calling `save` method on the model instance. Replace `p.save` with `p.save()`.